# d3.js empty data array error handling

Tags: javascript, validation, d3.js, charts

I am working on updating d3 chart via socket.io. Currently, my codes are almost the same as [this d3 example](https://jsfiddle.net/npzjLng9/2/).

Question: How can I just plot an emply chart when my initial data array is empty, i.e, in the above fiddle example, how can I plot an empty chart (with only axises and no data point) by setting

```
var data = []
```

instead of

```
var data = [
  {"Uhrzeit":"05:00","Durchschn":"0","Anz":"0","Gesamt":"0"},
  {"Uhrzeit":"05:01","Durchschn":"0","Anz":"0","Gesamt":"0"},
  //...
]
```

When clicking button `update new data`, the chart can still be updated.

(If making the array empty directly, there is an error `TypeError: Cannot read property of 'Uhrzeit' of undefined`.)

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you get that error is because your domain is defined based on the range of values in your data array.

```
  main_x.domain([data[0].Uhrzeit, data[data.length - 1].Uhrzeit]); 

//line 98 and lines below it will also give error
```

you can just set a condition that if data.length==0 then give a fixed value of domain(hard-coded). like:

```
main_x.domain([0, 100]);
```

Also next you will need to make sure that the you do not plot path when your data array is empty again by checking data.length==0

```
//DO NOT RUN THIS IF ARRAY IS EMPTY
main.append("path")
  .datum(data)
  .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
  .attr("class", "line line0")
  .attr("d", main_line0);
```

This is how you can get existing code to work.

Here's what I have been doing uptil now.

1. Create a seperate function makeGraph which is called onLoad.
2. In this function add hard-coded values for domain of both axis. Also do not try to plot the line here(path for main_line0 and main_line1).
3. Create function updateGraph which is called on clicking update. Do not make any changes here you can just copy the existing code here as it is.

I hope this helps point you in right direction to solve your problem.

Comment: The answer is great. Thank you @hunters30